# How to show/hide button in its click event before and after a synchronous ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to hide the "Pdf export" button and show loading icon on the start of the button click event and then I need to wait for my ajax request to end and reverse the button state.

But as it is a synchronous ajax call, hide/show button before it, is not visible in the browser as it is reversed again at the end.

```
$("#ActualButton").hide();
$("#loadingSpinner").show();

$.ajax({               
     url: "/Controller/Action",
     type: 'POST',
     async: false,
     success: function (data) 
      {
      }
});

$("#ActualButton").show();
$("#loadingSpinner").hide();
```

**Q1:** How to make the button change visible in Browser?

**Q2:** Also is there any way to detect completion of ajax call other than making it synchronous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your questions are connected. You can use several callback functions to detect the completion of the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({               
  url: "/Controller/Action",
  success: function (response) {
   // do something with the response
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    // do something wiht the xhr object, eg display the error 
  },
  complete: function() {
    // do something no matter what the response code was
  }
});
```

You do not need to, and actually should not make the ajax call synchronous. This will most likely lead to unpleasent user experience, in the best case, or unexpected behaviour that will be hard to debug.

```
$('#actualButton').on('click', function() {
    let $btn = $(this);
    $btn.hide(); // hide your button
    $("#loadingSpinner").show();
    $.ajax({               
      url: "/Controller/Action",
      success: function (response) {
        alert('Action was successful!'); // alert a success message
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.responseText); // show the response text
      },
      complete: function() {
        $btn.show(); // show the button again
        $("#loadingSpinner").hide(); // hide the loading spinner
      }
    });
});
```